# pgSQL query to get the count of sold items in last 3 (or any number of) days

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get the number of items sold in last 3 days by this query

```
Select COUNT(*) 
FROM "products" 
WHERE ("products"."SKU" = 'RAND100') 
  and ("isSold" = true) 
  and ("products"."createdAt" > NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days')
```

Instead of returning the count of items sold in last 3 days it is returning the count of items sold since the beginning of the time

NOTE: `createdAt` is a timstamp with timezone column.

Comment: Seems like you're asking for products that were created in the last 3 days rather than sold? What columns do you have on `products`?

Comment: `("products"."createdAt" < NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days')`  => `("products"."createdAt" > NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days')`

Comment: The sold item is stored on the product table? It seems to me that you have a big design flaw

Comment: @JorgeCampos lets treat the products table as a stock or inventory table. I understand the design flaw you are talking about. any solution ?

Comment: @DanielLyons there is a column "isSold" which is set to true

Comment: I don't think you are storing the information you need to perform the query you want to perform.

Comment: It would be good to see the structure of the products table. To see if what you want is even feasible with your current design.

Comment: @JorgeCampos problem solved. This query is fine the problem was the structure of my table :)

Comment: Great, add it as your own answer.

Comment: You need to use `>` not `<` in the condition for `createdAt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in question is fine, the problem was the structure of my database @DanielLyons was right my database was missing the information needed to perform that query. So it was as simple as adding a `sellingDate` column in my table.

Comment: The `<` would still be wrong - even with a different column.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

select * from tab
where DateCol between adddate(now(),-7) and now()

Comment: There is no `adddate()` function in Postgres